# How can I download a PDF file from a path or folder using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Good afternoon, I have an asp.net project and I would like that through an asp.net c # form a patient can download a certificate from a path or folder through their identification number or code, the folder it contains contains pdf and are organized by ID number

Thank you

Comment: Your question is too broad and is not aligned with the community guideline. Please write the problem you are facing, what you have tried so far, share some of your codes. Also correct the tags. Is the question about asp.net or asp.net.mvc - two very different technologies.

Answer (score 0):

> Due to your vague description, I am not sure if you are an mvc project
> or a core project.

The following is a case of downloading pdf in each project, please refer to：

### In mvc:

```
        public ActionResult DownLoad()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DownLoad(string id)
        {
            //PdfFiles is the name of the folder where these pdf files are located
            var path = Server.MapPath("~/PdfFiles/pdf" + id + ".pdf");  
            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, "application/pdf", Path.GetFileName(path)); 
        }
```

View:

```
<form  method="post" action="DownLoad">
    Pdf Id: <input id="Text1" type="text" name="id" />
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the test result:
[image]

### In Core:

```
       public IActionResult DownLoad()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DownLoad(string id)
        {
           //here i put the PdfFiles folder in the wwwroot folder
            var path = Path.Combine(
                           Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                           "wwwroot", "PdfFiles/pdf" + id + ".pdf");

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, "application/pdf", Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
```

View:

```
<form asp-action="DownLoad" method="post">
     Pdf Id: <input id="Text1" type="text"  name="id"/>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]